# Rename large number of column headers in dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Not sure if this is possible.

I have a dataframe with about 90 columns in it. I need to rename a specific number (~50) of these columns to different names. These columns would be spread throughout the dataframe (i.e. not the first or last 50).

Is there a quick way to do it, without using the method given by the pandas [docs](http://pandas.DataFrame.rename) (example below)?

```py
df.rename(index={0: "x", 1: "y", 2: "z"})
   A  B
x  1  4
y  2  5
z  3  6
```

Edit: This is the code that is being used to create the dataframe:

```py
# Function to import data from ARIC json file to dataframe

def ARIC_IMP(path):
    with open(path) as Aric:
        d = json.load(Aric)

    ARIC_IMP = json_normalize(d)
    return ARIC_IMP
```

Edit 2:

Clarification: The names of the fields in each json file can vary, depending on the source. Each always has about 90 columns (+/- 10), with between 65 - 70 having standardised names, and 20 being dynamically named (and vary by source). Of the 90 columns, I need to rename about 50 to specific names, so that they match other data coming from another source.

The 50 columns do not always appear in the json files, and when they do, they do will not be adjacent to each other.

Comment: What is the problem with method from the docs?

Comment: How do you currently hold the data of the old and new names?

Comment: Currently names are imported when the data is imported from the json. The 90 column names change depending on the json, but about 70 of them stay the same. I need to change 50 of those to a new name.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.columns` with a list of your column names.

```
name_list = ['name1','name2'...]
df.columns = name_list
```

This requires you to keep a list of your column names but based on what you've provided this will allow you to change column names in whatever order you please.

Comment: Currently names are imported when the data is imported from the json. The 90 column names change depending on the json, but about 70 of them stay the same. I need to change 50 of those to a new name

Comment: So your columns and data frame size are basically dynamic? How many use cases are there? There's a lot of contextual stuff here that im missing to give you a good answer.

Comment: They are dynamic. Will update with additional information.

Comment: So, if I understand this correctly, you have a completely dynamic data frame generated by a completely dynamic json. are the 50 that need to change always included?

Comment: Almost completely dynamic